# Looping through relational table

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql

Is it possible to loop through postgres while changing the values of Limit and offset. I want to loop through till the end of the relational table is reached. The reason I want to dynamically set Limit and offset is that I have very little virtual memory of 1 GB due to which my process is getting Killed.

Currently the approach I am taking is to manually set the values of limit and offset.

```
select *  from my_relational_table limit 1000 offset 0;
select *  from my_relational_table limit 1000 offset 1000;
select *  from my_relational_table limit 1000 offset 2000;
```

Is it possible to automate the process within postgres such that the loop stops when the end of the relational table is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. You can use a cursor and command FETCH.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html

Example:

```
postgres=# begin read only;
BEGIN
postgres=# declare xx cursor for select * from generate_series(1,100);
DECLARE CURSOR
postgres=# fetch 2 xx;
 generate_series 
-----------------
               1
               2
(2 rows)

postgres=# fetch 2 xx;
 generate_series 
-----------------
               3
               4
(2 rows)

postgres=# fetch 2 xx;
 generate_series 
-----------------
               5
               6
(2 rows)

postgres=# fetch 2 xx;
 generate_series 
-----------------
               7
               8
(2 rows)

postgres=# commit;
COMMIT
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Dont u think that still a lot of manual intervention is needed for postgres=# fetch 2 xx; I was talking about automating this process such that the user does not have to enter fetch 2 xx again and again

Comment: memory requests of psql processing can be decreased by \set FETCH_COUNT 1000 - other work is done by pager

Comment: @PavelStehule I have still not understood. Can you please elaborate with an example. Also thanks for replying

Comment: @PavelStehule Since here the selection is done on select * from generate_series(1,100); So how can I select the data from my relational table

Comment: you can use any select, not only generate series.

Comment: Execution of cursor is different than query execution. It only prepare query and will wait to FETCH statement. After FETCH it runs only to time, when produce requested rows, and then waits again.